# Joomla 3.2 - Turning Register Globals Off

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, web, joomla3.2

**Background:** I downloaded Joomla 3.2 directly from Joomla's website, extracted the contents and uploaded everything to a subfolder within my /public_html via FTP; with the host being **domain.com**. I access the frontend via www.{my_address}.com/Joomla3. I have .htaccess and php.ini in /public_html and .htaccess in my Joomla3 folder. It should also be noted that my php version is 5.3.13 and that I am using Filezilla for FTP transfers.

**Problem:** I am having trouble getting past the Pre-Installation Check. Everything under Recommended Settings is green while all the required settings are green...except the red "No" next to "Register Globals Off".

**Attempts:** From my desperate search through Google, here's what I've found/tried.

1. *Register_globals is turned off in php.ini by default in PHP5* - Yet the pre-installation check shows otherwise. Perhaps the host keeps it on?
2. *Put `register_globals = Off` in php.ini* - I placed it in /public_html/php.ini; No change. Also, I had to create php.ini myself. Perhaps it could be in the wrong location?
3. *Place `php_flag register_globals off` in .htaccess* - I placed it in /public_html/.htaccess; I receive a 500 Internal Server Error on both www.{my_address}.com and www.{my_address}.com/Joomla3. When I place the line in /public_html/Joomla3/.htaccess, www.{my_address}.com/Joomla3,  I receive Error 500 on just www.{my_address}.com/Joomla3.
4. *Go to Software/Services in HostGator Cpanel and click "php.ini QuickConfig"* - Though I know it's for a different host, I tried looking for a similar option/tool on Domain.com's control panel (whatever it may be called), but couldn't find one. Perhaps I overlooked it?
5. *Put php.ini in /public_html/yourserver/administrator/* - Copied the aforementioned php.ini file into /public_html/Joomla3/administrator; No change. I copied the same file into /public_html/Joomla3/installation; I receive Error 500 yet again.
6. *If you are running PHP5, name your initialization file php5.ini* - I changed php.ini to php5.ini; No change. I moved php5.ini to /administrator and /installation.

Those are all the attempts I can think of so far. Please let me know how to solve this. I appreciate all the help I can get. I've been working with Joomla 2.5 and I'd like to experience 3.2.

Note: I don't know what's with the formatting mishap in the 1st and 5th points. Please disregard the asterisks that were meant to italicize.

Comment: You should ask the support team at your hosting company.

Comment: That was my last resort, but it seems I may have to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I submitted a ticket to Domain.com's support staff with the request to turn Register_Globals off. They responded later that night after doing just that. I wish I could provide more details, but they hadn't provided any (even though I asked).

So, problem solved. Thanks anyways to those who provided ideas to try.

Answer (score 0):

Create `php.ini` and `.htaccess` files outside of your document root.

I will assume your document root is `/home/yourusername/public_html` then do the following:

Create `php.ini` file outside of the document root: `/home/yourusername/php.ini`.

Inside your `php.ini` file turn register_globals OFF:
    `register_globals = Off`

Create `.htaccess` file outside of the document root: `/home/yourusername/.htaccess`.

Inside your `.htaccess` file put:
    `SetEnv PHPRC /home/yourusername/php.ini`

Create a `phpinfo.php` file inside your document root: `/home/yourusername/public_html/phpinfo.php`

Inside your `phpinfo.php` file put this inside php tags: `phpinfo();`

Visit `phpinfo.php` and check the `Loaded Configuration File` - it should point to the new file.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I followed the instructions and www.{my_address}.com/phpinfo.php displays the php information. Otherwise, there's no change regarding the Joomla issue.

Comment: In the output of `phpinfo();` where does the `Loaded Configuration File` point to?

Comment: I believe it points to the original php.ini file because I don't recognize the location (/opt/users/.../php53/php.ini). I created the files in domain.com's file manager and I don't think they allow access that deep in their system.